# Count number of lines in a wrapped cell through vba

Tags: excel, cell, vba

How can I count the number of lines in a wrapped cell through vba code?

```
With Cells(1, 1)
    .WrapText = False
    height1 = .height
    .WrapText = True
    height2 = .height
End With 
MsgBox height2 / height1 & " Lines"
```

This code will not work since I have set row height to a fixed one (only one line is visible).

Also in my text, no line breaks since the data is entered through VBA code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the cell text has line breaks then what Dave (Edit: brettdj) suggested below will work nicely. However if it is one continuous text then have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889002/get-first-two-lines-of-text-from-a-wraped-cell-in-excel/9897363#comment12631761_9897363

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to subtract the length of the cell with linebreaks removed from the length of the unadjusted cell

Linebreaks can be replaced with a 0 length string using the worksheet function `Substitute`

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
Set c = ActiveCell
MsgBox Len(c.Value) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c.Value, Chr(10), vbNullString)) & " Linebreak(s)"
End Sub
```

**[Update; `Not a linebreak!`]**

As Sid points out in [Get first two lines of text from a wraped cell in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9889002/641067) this is tricky if working with font sizes (which can change).

I think the most foolproof way would be to copy the cell contents elsewhere (to an otherwise blank row), and autofit that row based on that cell to get the height.

Comment: This is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889002/get-first-two-lines-of-text-from-a-wraped-cell-in-excel/9897363#comment12631761_9897363. Lot of things have to be considered if the text doesn't have line breaks (CHR10) +1 though for this method which will work for lines separated by line breaks :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Fair point. Although based on the same askers prior question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9902628/641067 I think it is linebreak related.

Comment: In my text, no line breaks :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need an approximation :

```
Sub approx_number_of_lines()
    Set Rng = Selection

    a = Len(Rng.Value)
    'number of line returns
    b = Len(Rng.Value) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Rng.Value, Chr(10), vbNullString))
    c = Rng.ColumnWidth
    d = (a / c) + b
    'd = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(a / c, 1) + b
    Debug.Print d
End Sub
```